# JVM max heap size in Openshift doesn't change

Tags: java, memory, jvm, containers, openshift

I have a Java application that is being run on Openshift.
The Java is run via a docker-entrypoint.sh file

```
cd /usr/src/java_app
/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java -Xmx12g -jar application.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod >> /proc/self/fd/1 2> /proc/self/fd/1
```

My Openshift deploymemt memory part is as follows:

```
containers:
  - resources: 
      limits:
        memory: 12g
      requests:
        memory: 12g
```

I tried running the jar command with the following options:

```
-Xmx12g
-XX:MaxHeapSize=12g
-XX:MaxRAM=12g
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap
-XX:ErgoHeapSizeLimit=0
```

But when running

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep Heap
```

I always get a ~3g heap size, which is 25% of the 12g I gave the container.
This value changes to 4g if I give the container 16G.
Also, I can see that 'product' was reponsible to settign this value, so I guess it is not getting override  in the code.

Running

```
java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags
```

Returns

```
-XX:InitialHeapSize=187499968 -XX:MaxHeapSize=29999999488
```

I'd appreciate some help, given that memory is not that cheap

Comment: `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` and `java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags` start a *new* Java process and show the flags of this *new* Java process. To see the parameters of an existing Java process, use `jcmd` instead.

Comment: If you give all memory available to the heap you are going to have other memory issues. You should learn about Java memory settings first.

Comment: Than you very much,  indeed I was starting another process with no other configuration than default. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

What version of Java 8 are you using? older version of Java 8 are not able to correctly "see" the available memory

See this article on how to configure Java 8 depending of you version (ie before or after JDK 8u191)

https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-jvm-heap-size

If you are on OpenShift 4.12, check this article for many improvement with the latest version of Java 8 about the support of concerning cgroups v2, but you need the very last version of JDK 8:

https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2023/04/19/openjdk-8u372-feature-cgroup-v2-support#